# Have QueryDSL's constructor use a constant instead of a parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I use QueryDSL to build a query. The result has to be injected inside an object. The first column is the groupBy, the second is the value, and the third is a constant.

The constant is a problem because QueryDSL wants to make it a parameter, which leads to this error from Hibernate :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: 
  Parameters are only supported in SELECT clauses when used as part of a INSERT INTO DML statement 
  [select event.datetime, count(event), ?1]
```

The "?1" above should be directly a constant string "TOTAL".

Here is my code :

```
final Expression<String> TOTAL = Expressions.constant("total");
final StringExpression date = Expressions.stringTemplate("DATE_FORMAT({0},'%Y-%m-%d')", event.datetime);

query.select(Projections.constructor(Stat2DGraphDto.class, date, event.count(), TOTAL))
query.from(event).groupBy(date);
query.fetch();
```

If I remove TOTAL from the constructor, it works as intended, but I need this constant to prepare an UNION later.

Can I force QueryDSL to send the String as-this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

The developper of QueryDSL answered this behavior is a bug in Hibernate and they can't / won't fix it in QueryDSL. The solution I found is using `stringTemplate` with a quoted string :

```
final Expression<String> TOTAL = Expressions.stringTemplate("'total'");
```